# How to use parRF method so random forest will run faster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, r-caret

I would like to run random forest on a large data set: 100k * 400. When I use random forest it takes a lot of time. Can I use parRF method from caret package in order to reduce running time?
What is the right syntax for that?
Here is an example dataframe:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " TargetVar  Var1    Var2       Var3
 0        0        0         7
 0        0        1         1
 0        1        0         3
 0        1        1         7
 1        0        0         5
 1        0        1         1
 1        1        0         0
 1        1        1         6
 0        0        0         8
 0        0        1         5
 1        1        1         4
 0        0        1         2
 1        0        0         9
 1        1        1         2  ", header = TRUE)
```

I tried:

```
library('caret')
m<-randomForest(TargetVar ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, data = dat, ntree=100, importance=TRUE, method='parRF')
```

But I don't see too much of a difference. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that you don't see a difference is that you aren't using the `caret` package. You do load it into your environment with the `library()` command, but then you run `randomForest()` which doesn't use caret.

I'll suggest starting by creating a data frame (or [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)) that contains only your input variables, and a vector containing your outcomes. I'm referring to the recently updated [caret docs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf).

```
x <- data.frame(dat$Var1, dat$Var2, dat$Var3)
y <- dat$TargetVar
```

Next, verify that you have the `parRF` method available. I didn't until I updated my caret package to the most recent version (6.0-29).

```
library("randomForest")
library("caret")
names(getModelInfo())
```

You should see `parRF` in the output. Now you're ready to create your training model.

```
library(foreach)

rfParam <- expand.grid(ntree=100, importance=TRUE)

m <- train(x, y, method="parRF", tuneGrid=rfParam)
```

Comment: I think you need to define the `mtry` parameter instead of `ntree`.  This solution appears to produce an error: `Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : The tuning parameter grid should have columns mtry`

Comment: Yes, fantastic answer by @Lenwood. previous user pointed out, it doesnt work out for ntree given as parameter and mtry is required. So if you wish to use the default settings for randomForest package in R, it would be: ` rfParam <- expand.grid(mtry=round(sqrt(ncol(dataset))))  ` for categorical outcome

Comment: expand.grid(mtry=50, ntree = 1000,sampsize =90000, nodesize = 1, importance = TRUE, nPerm =2, oob.prox = TRUE) & m <- train(x, factor(y), method="parRF", tuneGrid=rfParam) . However, it is giving me following error Error in train.default(x, factor(y), method = "parRF", tuneGrid = rfParam) : 
  The tuning parameter grid should have columns mtry